# Unable to run apt-get command (Unit cups.service is masked)

Tags: apt, linux-mint

Today when I try to update some packages in "Update Manager" I get the error about cups-browsed, then I open terminal and type this command `sudo apt-get install -f`, output as below:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up cups-browsed (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) ...
Failed to start cups-browsed.service: Unit cups.service is masked.
invoke-rc.d: initscript cups-browsed, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package cups-browsed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cups-browsed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

What happened with my OS (Linux Mint 18) ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try the command

```
sudo systemctl unmask cups.socket
```

Hope that would help.